# Can't replace app store build with same version in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I have uploaded a build v1.0 at app store before approval I have removed the build due to some bugs. Now when I am trying to upload build again its giving me error of duplicate. Is there any way to upload the same version

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there may be a way do this. But you don't have to change the app version, you can just bump the build version and upload again.

**EDIT: You can bump the build version from Project > General > Build. (http://tinyurl.com/lzrffoe)**

Comment: Yes but this is my first release and i don't want to skip version 1.0

Comment: @TarunSeera, It will appear in the AppStore as v1.0. The build version is only visible to you. Just leave the app version to 1.0 and bump the build version to v1.1

Comment: How do you "bump the build version"?